# c++ fastest loop scan over 3D vector

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, stdvector

I want to know what is the fastest way as possible to perform a method on each element of a 3D vector.

Suppose we have:

```
std::vector<vector<vector<CLS>>> myVec;
```

I want to do the following loops in the fastest way as possible:

```
 for(int cycle=0;cycle<10;cycle++) // do it 10 times
 {
    for(int i=0;i<myVec.size();i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<myVec[i][constant].size();j++)
       {
           foo(myVec[i][constant][j]);
       }

    } 
 }
```

It's well mentioning that the middle term index is always **constant** in my case.
Is using std::vector fast enough or you suggest another type container?

Looking forward to your help.Thanks

Comment: Is there a better way to define a 3D array? There is just something funny about: `vector<vector<vector<type>>>`

Comment: @Derek No.I don't have better way in my mind. Do you?!

Comment: What architecture are you on? What's the target hardware spec?

Comment: Is your data rectangular? (all myVec[i][constant].size() are the same?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of iterators should be faster (you don't have to look up through the whole array on every call of `foo`).

```
typedef std::vector<CLS> v1;
typedef std::vector<v1> v2;
typedef std::vector<v2> v3;

for(int cycle=0;cycle<10;cycle++) // do it 10 times
{
    for(v3::const_iterator itOuter = myVec.begin(); itOuter != myVec.end(); ++itOuter)
    {
        const v1& vec = (*itOuter)[constant];
        for(v1::const_iterator itInner = vec.begin(); itInner != vec.end(); ++itInner)
            foo(*itInner);
    }
}
```

I didn't measure it, though (didn't even try to compile, so pardon any typos)

Comment: Why would using indexes make you have to look up through the whole array on every call? Iterators being faster than indexes are a common missconception, please don't spread it!

Comment: No @LuchianGrigore you are wrong. Iterator are faster! Look [here](http://ideone.com/7cGW4) and [here](http://ideone.com/euo9u).

Comment: @lionbest if you want to prove that, take a different example - something that can't appear to be faster because of numerous other reasons. Take a 1-d array and iterate over it, then I'll be convinced.

Comment: It's code for a 3-d non always rectangular array, not for a 1-d!

Comment: @lionbest if iterators are faster, they're faster regardless of the dimensions of the array, right?

Comment: I don't know why. But I just tested it and got a terrible time. About 10 times slower!!!

Comment: 10 times slower? If you're compiling with -O0, you may be right because of lots of function calls, but surely not with -O2 (which doesn't uses any methods at all, it basically breaks down to twalberg's loop). `myVec[i][j][k]` will break down to `*(*(*(myVec.begin() + i).begin() + j).begin() + k)` - for every call.

As a fact, the index solution has 10 lines more assembly code than the iterator solution if compiled with -O2 (g++ 4.5.3). On -O0 however, the iterator code is much longer, just as expected.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: In the inner loop, there are 3 index operations, which are three times "memory dereferencing" and three "add" operations. Using the iterators will remove the unnecessary dereferencing. It will also give you an additional speedup, if your array doesn't fit into your cache lines, so you have to access the 'real' RAM more often than really required.

Comment: @Mark you're under-estimating the compiler. But regardless, that has nothing to do with indexes vs iterators. You could just as well create an alias for the whole line.

Comment: Also, comparing the number of asm instructions is pointless. Running the code and measuring isn't.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Pointless is definitively the wrong word. Even a single ASM instruction DOES matter, if you loop through it often enough. But to convince you: Setting the vector's size to [1024][1][1024] and running the code with index ops (1000 cycles, constant = 0) gives an average of 2.225s on my mychine, while running the same code using iterators (same parameters) gives an average ov 2.224s. That's quite the same but definitively NOT slower. Changing the index size to [1024][1][1024*1024] and reducing the outer loop to 10 gives approx 32.347s for index and for 29.63s for iterators.

Comment: I never said it's slower, I'm saying they're the same. And they are. A single instruction counts only if it's executed. And then, only if the rest are the same. Not all instructions take as many cycles and they differ in microinstructions. So just comparing their numbers **IS** pointless.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17522/discussion-between-mark-and-luchian-grigore)

Comment: @Mark sorry, don't have time to talk now... :(

Comment: No problem. So I'll add one final comment and leaving this thread alone: 
Iterators implicitly force you to use loop variables which directly point to the memory you want to access. If you're using index operations, you can do that, too, but you're not enforced to. 
Depending on the size of the nested arrays, proper programming will give you a significant boost (and I'd say 3 seconds *ARE* significant) due to minimized memory access. With index operations, you need to keep that in mind. Iterators will give you this boost by default.

Answer (score 2):

The following would be faster:

```
for(int i=0, int vecSize = myVec.size();i<vecSize;i++)
{
   for(int j=0, int currentLineSize = myVec[i][constant].size();j<currentLineSize;j++)
   {
       foo(myVec[i][constant][j]);
       //copy-paste this 10 times instead of having the outer loop
   }
}
```

If you know anything about the sizes, you can perform some more unrolling.

Comment: @batistacori no, iterators are not faster.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the "fastest way possible" (and the least C++-ish way possible, although it's still valid C++) would be along these lines:

```
const unsigned dim1 = 10; //first dimension
const unsigned dim2 = 20; //second
const unsigned dim3 = 30; //third
const unsigned nElem = dim1 * dim2 * dim3;

CLS myVec[nElem];

CLS *p = myVec, *q = myVec + nElem;

while (p < q)
{ foo(*p);
  ++p;
}
```

This eliminates all the calculation of indices, since `foo()` seems to depend only on the value of the `CLS` element in question, not on its position in the array. Of course, accessing `myVec` in a 3D-ish way becomes more complex (`myVec[x * dim1 * dim2 + y * dim1 + z]` and so on - just making explicit all the indexing calculations C++ normally does for you...).

Changing the loop around to "slice" the array so that one dimension is kept constant would make it a little more complicated (essentially make it a doubly nested loop that adds an additional offset to the pointer at the termination of the inner loop). A bit like this (although I may have the dimensions reversed):

```
while (p < q)
{ CLS *r = p + dim3;
  while (p < r)
  { foo(*p);
    ++p;
  }
  p += dim2;
}
```

Comment: but dim1 , dim2, dim3 are not constant in my case.

Comment: @batistacori They don't necessarily need to be constant - I didn't see where they were specified in the original example (if they're not constant, you may need to do `CLS *myVec = new CLS[dim1*dim2*dim3];` instead of allocating them statically, though). The main point was to allocate one single-dimensional array and walk through it in order to a) provide cache locality and b) avoid repeated indexing calculations.

Comment: filling out 1D array from 3D array needs another nested loop!!! So there is no difference

Comment: Thanks. I got what you said. Indeed it is the fastest way so far

Answer (score 0):

You could create a recursive function object:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template<typename Container>
    void operator()(Container& container) {
        for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), *this);
    }
    void operator()(CLS cls) {
        // do what you want
    }
};

Foo foo;
foo(myVec);
```

Comment: Can you explain it little more? Why would it be faster?